# get data from usb weatherboard using PySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, embedded, sensors, pyserial

I am using USB Weatherboard V3 right now.

The data is sent every 1 seconds continously from /dev/ttyUSB* ... I have tried to get the data with PySerial but I still failed.

I just can get "RESET" in the output console. I can't get the data.

What I want is output like this :

```
SHT15 temperature: 2.5          75.1 deg F          
SHT15 humidity:                 65%                 
SHT15 dewpoint:                 62.7 deg F 
BMP085 pressure: 2 2011, 10:05:235.967 in Hg    FAIL
BMP085 temperature:             75.3 deg F          
TEMT6000 light:                 0.1%                
Weather meters wind speed: speci0.0 MPH         FAIL 
Weather meters wind direction:  -1 degrees      FAIL 
Weather meters rainfall:        0.00 inches     FAIL 
External power:                 0.00 Volts      FAIL
```

^ it come from minicom (unix serial program).

Can someone help me ?

Btw, this is my code currently :

```
import serial;
import io;
import time;
import os;

# Weather board script #    

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    try :
        print '===================================\n'
        print 'USB Weatherboard V3 - Python Script'
        print 'Connection datasheet : '
        print '(+) Port : /dev/ttyUSB0'
        print '(+) Baud rate : 9600'
        print '(+) Type : 8N1'
        print '===================================\n'
        ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, timeout=1, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=True)

        while True :
            arr = ser.readlines()
            for strarr in arr :
                s = strarr.decode('cp1252').replace('\00','')
                #s2 = s.encode('ascii');
                s2 = s
                if s2[1:3] != '[H' :
                    print s2
                    pass
                pass
            pass
    except :
        print 'Program exit !'
        pass
    finally :
        ser.close()

    pass
```

Please help me to correct it or if someone who has code it before me, please share with me :)

Weatherboard v3 datasheet : http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/USB_Weather_Board_V3_datasheet_110615.pdf

Weatherboard v3 product : https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10586

Comment: I have give more information :) ... Actually it didn't give error, but I can't get the same output as minicom give to me.

Comment: In the source code, you mention `problem: unknown character byte`. That should be the last/first of many lines of error output.

Comment: oh no that one is previous error ... now that is no error but my script didn't give me the measurement like minicom give me ...

Comment: I am curious that I made some mistake when I set parameter in serial.Serial( ... ) constructor ... I don't really understand about hardware :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = ser.readlines()
```

reads *all* lines from the serial device, and only then returns. Since your device is sending data ad infinitum, you should just iterate over it to get the lines while they're written, like this:

```
import serial
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, timeout=1,
                       xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=True) as s:
        for line in s:
            print(s)
```

Comment: I have tried that but still sometimes the weatherboard can't be connected. I must replug it until the green light dimmed.

Comment: @psuedobot Do I understand you comment correctly in that this answer solved your original problem in most cases, but there are some connection errors? If so, please open a new question after making sure it's really your program that's at fault (if you don't run the program, do you still see the same behavior?)

Comment: but I think your solution correct (for connection parameter serial) .. i will mark is as correct answer